# What guidelines exist for members discussing sites they run or work on?

Tags: discussion

What is the policy for members who run webapps, particularly regarding questions tagged [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec)? Are disclaimers required or suggested? Can those members work on the relevant wiki tags?

For example, if I worked for Yammer (I don't), in what way might my contributions to questions tagged [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec), [chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat), [intranet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intranet), and [yammer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yammer) and to the wiki pages for those tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, an OnStartups meta question was recently asked about basically the same thing:
 [Are users allowed to offer their/suggest their own services?](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/3/are-users-allowed-to-offer-their-suggest-their-own-services)

The top-voted answer there suggests that **yes, this should be allowed, provided that**:

> 1. The suggestion adds value to the answer, rather than a shameless plug.
>      There must be enough additional
>      information to earn the plug.
> 2. Users should state they are plugging their own service

I think that works pretty well for this site too.

Comment: I like this response, though I'm going to wait a little while to see if there are good counterarguments before marking it "accepted."